# How to make consistent url format for news item across translations in Sitefinity?

Tags: url-rewriting, sitefinity

My application have Arabic and English languages enabled. When the url is generated for news items, the date component is present in the URL and its different for each language. Gregorian date for English translation and Hijri date components for arabic item's url.

The requirement here is to have same date (Gregorian) in both items url, is there any fix or options available to change this?

Thanks
Salam

Answer (score 1):

That's not gonna be easy, because when the Thread is in AR culture, then calling date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") returns something completely different compared to when the Thread is in EN culture, as you correctly pointed out.

What Sitefinity allows you to do, is to change the urlformat of the news items, so the easiest way would be to remove the PublicationDate from the url format altogether. As a result the news url will not have a date portion.

If that's acceptable for you, then check how to do it here:
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-change-url-format-for-built-in-modules-with-single-content-type

Simply create this urlFormat parameter and set its value to

```
/[UrlName]
```

Comment: Fully agree that removing the date portion is the better option (even for English, with the audience potentially confusing MM/DD with DD/MM. That said, the default AR culture (with hijri calendar) will continue to cause you issues with regards to dates (events, api´s etc). 

Its best to go to https://localhost/Sitefinity/Administration/Settings/Advanced then choose Cultures > PredefinedLanguages > Arabic-ar and update the fields to not be (Saudi Arabian) by default, but select for example ar-JO to ensure nothing will use hijri.